# Build hangs in one place constantly

Tags: unity-game-engine

The build always gets up in the same place no matter what I do and no matter what settings I change
[image]

I already looked at the logs, and looked at other forums - does anyone have a similar error thread, but I could not find anything worthwhile

Comment: What platform are you building for? How long do you wait? Some of our builds take many hours if not using a cache server. What are the last dozen or so lines of editor.log when this happens?

Comment: @RetiredNinja 
Android
1 time i wait 5 hours,
Its small project - child pazzle,
I check logs - all good, i dont saw errors

Comment: I wasn't asking about errors in the logs, I was interested in the last few steps. Have you tried another project? Try building for Windows standalone.

Comment: I had an almost blank project take 8 hours on my work laptop due to settings on the laptop. Same build on my own machine at home. Minutes. If you have encrypted disks with certain settings and add anti virus and other things 5 hours for a first build is not a long enough wait.

Comment: @RetiredNinja for pc build all good, but idk why android build dont working

Comment: @BugFinder is so small project 2d pazzle, build work in windows but i cannot build for android

Comment: No. You just need to leave it till it builds. It should then be quicker next time

Comment: @BugFinder small game, rly 5+ hours wait, my another project weight 5+ gb build in 5-15 minutes

Comment: As i said. Its likely down to something on your machine.   I gave you an example of how a near empty project 2 scripts and 1 prefab took 8 hours on my work machine and why. And less than 15 mins on my home machine

Comment: @BugFinder i fixed it now, its very easy problem